# Why does having no autocommit facility mean that all queries execute within a transaction in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

From https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial

> **PostgreSQL does not have an autocommit facility which means that all
>   queries will execute within a transaction.**
>
> Execution within a transaction is a very good thing, it ensures data
>   integrity and allows for appropriate error handling. However there are
>   **queries that can not be run from within a transaction**. Take the
>   following example.
>
> ```
> #/usr/bin/python2.4
> #
> #
>
> import psycopg2
>
> # Try to connect
>
> try:
>     conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='template1' user='dbuser' password='mypass'")
> except:
>     print "I am unable to connect to the database."
>
> cur = conn.cursor()
> try:
>     cur.execute("""DROP DATABASE foo_test""")
> except:
>     print "I can't drop our test database!"
> ```
>
> This code would actually fail with the printed message of "I can't
>   drop our test database!" **PostgreSQL can not drop databases within a
>   transaction**, it is an all or nothing command. **If you want to drop the
>   database you would need to change the isolation level of the database**
>   this is done using the following.
>
> ```
> conn.set_isolation_level(0)
> ```
>
> You would place the above immediately preceding the DROP DATABASE
>   cursor execution.

I was wondering why

- "PostgreSQL does not have an autocommit facility which means that all queries will execute within a transaction."
- "PostgreSQL can not drop databases within a transaction"
- "If you want to drop the database you would need to change the isolation level of the database"

Thanks.

---

Update: 
[What does autocommit mean in postgresql and psycopg2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880309/what-does-autocommit-mean-in-postgresql-and-psycopg2) answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the 3 are related to Python and its DB connector library, not the PostgreSQL itself:

1. PostgreSQL has an `autocommit` and it is active by default - which means that every SQL statement is immediately executed. When you start a transaction block, this autocommit mode is disabled until you finish the transaction (either by COMMIT or ROLLBACK)
2. The operation of destroying a database is implemented in a way where you can not run it from inside a transaction block. Also keep in mind that unlike most other databases PostgreSQL allows almost all DDL statements (obviously not the DROP DATABASE one) to be executed inside a transaction.
3. Actually you can not drop a database if anyone (including you) is currently connected to this database - so it does not matter what is your isolation level, you still have to connect to another database (e.g. `postgres`)

Comment: Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869619/does-dropping-a-database-have-to-be-done-not-in-any-transaction

Comment: From what you described, both three points seem to issues of PostgreSQL only, not the driver Psycopg2. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks. I am confused about what autocommit means in postgresql and in psycopg2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880309/what-does-autocommit-mean-in-postgresql-and-psycopg2

Comment: @Tim I assume that what you call an "issue" is simply a misunderstanding of how the things work. When you start a transaction you effectively tell the database that you want to execute **several** queries `at once` instead of one by one (`autocommit` means `one by one`)