# Does dropping a database have to be done not in any transaction?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

From https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2_Tutorial

> PostgreSQL can not drop databases within a transaction, it is an all
>   or nothing command. If you want to drop the database you would need to
>   change the isolation level of the database this is done using the
>   following.
>
> ```
> conn.set_isolation_level(0)
> ```
>
> You would place the above immediately preceding the DROP DATABASE
>   cursor execution.

Why "If you want to drop the database you would need to change the isolation level of the database"?
In particular, why do we need to change the isolation level to 0? (If I am correct, 0 means `psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_READ_COMMITTED`)

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/51859484/156458

> The operation of destroying a database is implemented in a way which
>   prevents undoing it - therefore **you can not run it from inside a
>   transaction because transactions are always undoable.** Also keep in
>   mind that unlike most other databases PostgreSQL allows almost all DDL
>   statements (obviously not the DROP DATABASE one) to be executed inside
>   a transaction.
>
> Actually you can not drop a database if anyone (including you) is
>   currently connected to this database - so it does not matter what is
>   your isolation level, you still have to connect to another database
>   (e.g. postgres)

"you can not run it from inside a transaction because transactions are always undoable". Then how can I drop a database not from inside a transaction?

---

I found my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51880577/156458

Comment: With PHP you can destroy a database like this `$db = new PDO('some other database, e.g. postgres'); $db->query('DROP DATABASE your_original_database');` I do not know how to do it in Python.

Comment: Connect to a different database. Do not open transaction. Drop the database you want.

Comment: @KamilG. Each SQL command is a transaction by default, how can I make a command not in any transaction?

Comment: I bet you just have to perform `self.conn.set_isolation_level(0)` right before the query execution and after database change. Then, switch back to old isolation level. Make sure to store it in a variable beforehand.

Comment: @KamilG. You meant twice before and after drop database?

Comment: I believe the order should be like this: 1. connect to different db; 2. store isolation level; 3. set isolation level to 0; 4. execute drop database query; 5. set isolation level to original (stored before operation)

Comment: @KamilG. Thanks. Do I need to do the same when working in psql shell?

Comment: @Tim default isolation level for Postgres db is `READ_COMMITTED`. This is simpler for psql though. What you need to do is actually: 1. connect to different db; 2. execute drop database query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with psycopg2 so I can only provide steps to be performed.

Steps to be taken to perform `DROP DATABASE` from **Python**:

1. Connect to a different database, which you don't want to drop
2. Store current isolation level in a variable
3. Set isolation level to 0
4. Execute `DROP DATABASE` query
5. Set isolation level back to original (from #2)

---

Steps to be taken to perform `DROP DATABASE` from **PSQL**:

1. Connect to a different database, which you don't want to drop
2. Execute `DROP DATABASE` query

**Code in psql**

```
\c second_db
DROP DATABASE first_db;
```

---

Remember, that there can be no live connections to the database you are trying to drop.

Comment: Thanks.  (1) In PostgreSQL, each SQL command is a transaction by default. According to the quote in my post,  we must drop database not within any transaction.  Can changing to the isolation level ` READ_COMMITTED` for Postgres db  make drop database not in any transaction?  (2) Why is the case for psycopg2 require explicit change and restore the isolation level, while the case for psql does, given that the default isolation level is READ_COMMIT for the postgresql server?

Comment: (1) You shouldn't worry about implicit transactions within PostgreSQL. We're talking about explicit ones, so you just can't start a transaction with `BEGIN`. (2) I believe that setting isolation level to `0` actually means a constant value `ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT` but you'd have to check. This means that we're turning off explicit transaction opening. There's no need for changing actual isolation level within Postgres, as I guess it does not matter.

Comment: Thanks. I am confused about what autocommit means in postgresql and in psycopg2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51880309/what-does-autocommit-mean-in-postgresql-and-psycopg2