# What does autocommit mean in postgresql and psycopg2?

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

Does autocommit mean the same in PostgreSQL and Psycopg2?

From PostgreSQL manual

> By default (without  BEGIN ),
>   PostgreSQL executes transactions in “autocommit” mode, that is, **each statement is executed in its own
>   transaction** and **a commit is implicitly performed at the end of the statement (if execution was successful,
>   otherwise a rollback is done)**.

Does it mean that autocommit will create a transaction for each command?

From [Psycopg2 driver's manual](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control)

> It  is  possible  to  set  the  connection  in autocommit  mode:  this
>   way  **all  the  commands executed will be immediately committed** and no
>   rollback is possible. A few commands (e.g. CREATE DATABASE, VACUUM…)
>   require to be run outside any transaction: in order to be able to run
>   these commands from Psycopg, the connection must be in autocommit
>   mode: you can use the autocommit property.

[and](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html?highlight=isolation%20level#psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

> ```
> psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT
> ```
>
> **No transaction is started when commands are executed and no commit() 
>   or rollback() is  required.**  Some  PostgreSQL  command  such  as
>   CREATE  DATABASE  or VACUUM can’t run into a transaction: to run such
>   command use:
>
> ```
> >>> conn.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)
> ```

Does "all  the  commands executed will be immediately committed" mean that autocommit in Psycopg2 creates a transaction for each command?

Does "No transaction is started when commands are executed and no commit()  or rollback() is  required" mean  that autocommit in Psycopg2 will prevent a transaction created for each command?

Does "Some  PostgreSQL  command  such  as CREATE  DATABASE  or VACUUM can’t run into a transaction: to run such  command, enable autocommit mode"  mean  that autocommit in Psycopg2 will prevent a transaction created only for some commands (CREATE DATABASE or VACUUM)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every PostgreSQL statement is running in a transaction.

PostgreSQL itself *only* knows autocommit mode, which means that each statement will run in its own transaction if you don't start a transaction explicitly.

Statements like `VACUUM` cannot run in the same transaction with other statements.

If you are not using autocommit in psycopg2, the driver has to simulate non-autocommit mode by explicitly starting a transaction when the first statement is run.

Comment: Thanks. (1)Could you guess what autocommit mean in Psycopg2? Does it mean the following command(s) are not run in any transaction, by "A few commands (e.g. CREATE DATABASE, VACUUM…) require to be run outside any transaction: in order to be able to run these commands from Psycopg, the connection must be in autocommit mode: you can use the autocommit property",  "No transaction is started when commands are executed and no commit() or rollback() is required" , and "Some PostgreSQL command such as CREATE DATABASE or VACUUM can’t run into a transaction: to run such command, enable autocommit mode"?

Comment: (2) In postgreSQL, does drop database also run in a transaction, no matter how? Why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869619/does-dropping-a-database-have-to-be-done-not-in-any-transaction

Comment: (3) In postgreSQL, when you said "Every PostgreSQL statement is running in a transaction", does it apply to autocommit only?  if autocommit is disabled, is it still "every PostgreSQL statement is running in a transaction" ?

Comment: I tried to extend the answer to make it clearer. If you don't set autocommit mode in psycopg2, you will probably get an error if you run `VACUUM` and friends. `DROP DATABASE` is also one of these commands. Note that these commands *still*run inside a transaction: if they fail, they will have no effect.

Comment: Thanks.   postgresql manual says "CREATE DATABASE  cannot be executed inside a transaction block." By a transaction block, does it mean only those created explicitly? Does create database still have to execute in its own transaction?

Comment: Right, a "transaction block" is an explicitly started transaction (`BEGIN;` - statements - `COMMIT;`).

Comment: Besides `COMMIT`, does `ROLLBACK` end a transaction?

Comment: Yes. For the basics of transaction management, please read the documentation.